# extjs 3.4 how to get element by name

Tags: extjs, extjs3

How can I get a html element by its name or css class in extended js 3.4?
Ext.getCmp() I think only supports getting elements by their id's.

I need this to add a Ext.Tip to every gridpanels cell

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DomQuery](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.DomQuery) for that purpose.

Another approach would be to use [Column Renderer](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.Column-cfg-renderer) where you can set tooltips by adding them to `metaData.attr` (second argument of the renderer function).

Comment: I tried metaData.attr that does work, but the problem is I need a custom tooltip with fixed width and height greater the 500 px. Any idea how I can do this in ext 3.4?

Comment: It's long time since I've used 3.x, but if I recall correctly, there are attributes like `qwidth`, `qtitle`, etc. that can be added to the target element to tweak the quick tip appearance. See [QuickTips Docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.QuickTips) for details

Comment: yes there are, but qwidth supports a maximum o 500px and qheight is redundant, as it purely depends on the content that it has, so if it does not have enough content, the height will wrapp around the content

Comment: Well, then only get elements with DomQuery and iterate to create the custom tooltips.

Comment: how can i make a custom tooltip?

Comment: Just instantiate the ToolTip class with appropriate config options. See [ToolTip Documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.ToolTip) and [ToolTip Examples](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/examples/simple-widgets/qtips.html)